# Return an object depending on matching parameter

Tags: c#, linq

To make my long story short i had to improvise this code a little:

```
public class Faerie
{
    public string Name;
}

public class Example
{
    List<Faerie> faeries = new List<Faerie>() { 
        new Faerie { Name = "Wild Faerie" } ,
    new Faerie { Name = "Smoke Faerie" },
    new Faerie { Name = "Red Faerie" }
    };

    string[] faerieNamesFromInput = new string[] { "White Faerie", "Wild Faerie", "Dark Faerie" };

    public Faerie ReturnMatchedFromInput()
    {

    }
}
```

How can i return a Fairy object from the fairies list if its name matches a name from the user input? Like for instance, here i want to return the Faerie with name Wild Faerie because it's name matches.Is there a short LINQ way for that or i have to go with for loop?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty basic `Where`/`FirstOrDefault` query.

Comment: This is pretty basic, but to be honest this is the second time that i want to use LINQ because i don't use it designing my simple games and my knowledge of it is at beginners level

Comment: @Groo it's only simple if you know the answer.

Comment: @James: Sure, but googling is also pretty simple. This question has been asked and answered dozens of times. *That's* whats simple. Hence the "what have you tried" question. The number of different threads I get by googling for "linq find item from another list" or "linq find string in list" is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return multiple matches

```
faeries.Where(x => faerieNamesFromInput.Contains(x.Name));
```

If you want to return the *first* matched then

```
faeries.FirstOrDefault(x => faerieNamesFromInput.Contains(x.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
var result = faeries.FirstOrDefault(x => faerieNamesFromInput.Contains(x.Name));
```

Make sure to include `System.LINQ` namespace.